# Java - Cassandra - cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Obj

Tags: java, casting, cassandra, optional-parameters, key-value-store

I am getting this (weird?) error with Java 8 and Cassandra

```
List<ByteBuffer> list = a list full of ByteBuffer objects; 
ByteBuffer single = a single ByteBuffer object; 

Select.Where statement1 = qb.select().from(TABLE_NAME).where(QueryBuilder.in(primaryKey, QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));

pstatement= session.prepare(statement1);

new BoundStatement(pstatement).bind(list) OK         
new BoundStatement(pstatement).bind(single) EXCEPTION (see below)

public BoundStatement bind(Object... values) {
                //blah   }
```

> java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Obj

Any idea why this is happening?

SOLUTION: OK, I found the solution. The problem is that Cassandra does not accept only one key in the IN clause. The error message is misleading in any case. If I change the IN by EQ this just works.

thanks

Altober

Comment: Please provide a **minimal complete example** allowing us to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much it the exception is triggered as soon as blind(single) is called, does not even attempt to enter into the method. Both list and single are provided externally and the function is part of Cassandra, but I am not sure it has to do with Cassandra.